# Adding quotes to a string in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, escaping, string-concatenation

I have this code:

```
a = "xyz"  
g = "abcd " & a
```

After running it, the value of `g` is `abcd xyz`.

However, I want quotes around the value of `a` in `g`. After running the code, `g` should be `abcd "xyz"` instead.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can escape by doubling the quotes

```
g="abcd """ & a & """"
```

or write an explicit `chr()` call

```
g="abcd " & chr(34) & a & chr(34)
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to use double double quotes to escape the double quotes (lol):

```
g = "abcd """ & a & """"
```

Comment: Escaping a special character with itself is not unusual, see double backslashes in C-style languages, or double single quotes in SQL.

Comment: very funny :) yea. that's the way to go in VBS

Answer (score 8):

I usually do this:

```
Const Q = """"

Dim a, g
a = "xyz"  
g = "abcd " & Q & a & Q
```

If you need to wrap strings in quotes more often in your code and find the above approach noisy or unreadable, you can also wrap it in a function:

```
a = "xyz"  
g = "abcd " & Q(a)

Function Q(s)
  Q = """" & s & """"
End Function
```

Answer (score 8):

The traditional way to specify quotes is to use `Chr(34)`. This is error resistant and is not an abomination.

```
Chr(34) & "string" & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
a="""xyz"""  
g="abcd " & a
```

Or:

```
a=chr(34) & "xyz" & chr(34)
g="abcd " & a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can improve on these answers as I've used them all, but my preference is declaring a constant and using that as it can be a real pain if you have a long string and try to accommodate with the correct number of quotes and make a mistake.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I designed a simple approach using single quotes when forming the strings and then calling a function that replaces single quotes with double quotes.

Of course this approach works as long as you don't need to include actual single quotes inside your string.

```
Function Q(s)

    Q = Replace(s,"'","""")

End Function
```

...

```
user="myself"
code ="70234"
level ="C"

r="{'User':'" & user & "','Code':'" & code & "','Level':'" & level & "'}"
r = Q(r)
response.write r
```

...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer to use double and triple quotation marks unsatisfactory. I used a nested DO...LOOP to write an ASP segment of code. There are repeated quotation marks within the string.  When I ran the code:

```
thestring = "<asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom=""" & bottom & """ HotSpotMode=""PostBack"" Left="""& left & """    PostBackValue=""" &xx & "." & yy & """ Right=""" & right & """ Top=""" & top & """/>"
```

the output was:
<`asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom="28

```
 'Changing the code to the explicit chr() call worked:

thestring = "<asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom=""" & bottom & chr(34) & " HotSpotMode=""PostBack"" Left="""& left & chr(34) & " PostBackValue=""" &xx & "." & yy & chr(34) & " Right=""" & right & chr(34) & " Top=""" & top & chr(34) &"/>"
```

The output:

```
<asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom="28" HotSpotMode="PostBack" Left="0" PostBackValue="0.0" Right="29" Top="0"/>
```

Comment: chr(34) works. But so does escaping the double quotes. Your top example code would not output what you claim it did; something else was wrong there. Your "working" example even includes escaping, proving that it does work.

Comment: The numbers in the output code were from the values assigned to the variables. This code  is just a snippet. The whole output was a 178 KB file. Double and triple quotes do work, but not for what I needed. I don't begin to know why, but that doesn't change the fact that it didn't work as it should have in my case. I was writing the output to a file.  It could be that multiple escapes inside nested loops using one interpreted code to write another while writing to a file was too much for the VBscript interpreter.