# Call a bat from a bat with parameters

Tags: parameters, vbscript, batch-file

```
     main.bat contains:
     cscript treat.vbs /a:"the name of file"
```

REm: the name of file contains many spaces

```
     treat.vbs contains:
     dim param: param_input=Wscript.Arguments.Named("a")
     msgbox param_input
     shell.run "second.bat" param_input & " " & ""myfile.out""

     second.bat contains:(just for purpose of test)
     echo %1
     echo %2
```

When running the main.bat, msgbox shows a popup with all the name file (including all spaces contained within the name of file, while the echo message echo %1 shows the name of file cutting down.

How can I do to workaround that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be "Call a bat from a **vbs** with parameters"

You dim `param` but use `param_input`

```
dim param: param_input=Wscript.Arguments.Named("a")
```

Your concatenation of the cmd to .run is faulty:

```
>> s = "second.bat" param_input & " " & ""myfile.out""
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Expected end of statement
```

One way of getting it right is using and replacing ' with " to avoid VBScript's "" escape in concatenations:

```
>> param_input = "the name of file"
>> s = Replace("'second.bat' '" & param_input & "' 'myfile.out'", "'", """")
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
"second.bat" "the name of file" "myfile.out"
```

For discussion/other ways see [How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro-m81189.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the parameters to double-quotes to make the space be part of the parameter. And you need to escape those double-quotes by doubling them in VBS.

```
shell.run "second.bat """ & param_input & """ ""myfile.out"""
```

I could not include whole example, as you code does not even compile.

Refer also to question [Adding quotes to a string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942554/850848).