# Calling exe in the VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to pass an exe path in the VBScript to call it automatically. Please suggest.

Path to pass :

```
C:\Program Files\TSVN\bin\Tor.exe"/command:repobrowser
```

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(""C:\Program Files\TSVN\bin\TProc.exe"/command:repobrowser"") 'Not working
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx

Comment: The syntax highlighting actually shows up your issue the string is not correctly terminated due to not escaping the command quotes properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotes have not been escaped correctly causing in string to be incorrectly terminated, try this;

```vb
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\TSVN\bin\TProc.exe""/command:repobrowser")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

The string is equivalent to

```
"C:\Program Files\TSVN\bin\TProc.exe"/command:repobrowser
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Adding quotes to a string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942573/692942)