# How do I put quotation marks into quotation mark (vbs, sendkeys)

Tags: shell, vbscript, sendkeys, wscript.shell

I need to type " into notepad with VBS script.

I have this code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad"
wscript.sleep 500
WshShell.sendkeys "some "text""
```

But it shows an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double up the quotes inside or you can use `chr(34)`

```
Text = "my ""example"" of doubled quotes"
Text = "use " & Chr(34) & "chr ()" & Chr(34) & " function"
```

Comment: Single quotes do not work like this in VBScript. They're used for comment only.

Comment: How is this different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942573/692942) from over 11 years ago?

Comment: @user692942 I didn't search for an answer so no idea? Probably not a great deal of difference? Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it does the fact you have to ask that tells me you have no idea of what [so] is meant to be.

Comment: I wasn't asking in all honesty.